# Make pre-commit hooks ignore submodules

Tags: git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a git repo with a couple of submodules whose code contents are out of my control. I would like to ignore these submodules in all [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hooks. Is there any way of achieving this short of manually specifying the folders in which these submodules reside for every individual hook?

Comment: I think this is the automatic behaviour, your repo won't  see submodule changes unless you `git submodule update`. If you have local changes in those submodules you could `checkout` them if you don't need them

Answer (score 1):

submodules should be ignored by default -- they get a special `type` tag of `submodule` which usually doesn't go through the normal git hooks (which by default have a filter of `[file]`).

my guess is your configuration escapes the normal way of using hooks and does something like `flake8 .` -- in which case you should switch to filename-based hooks.  It's impossible to know without seeing your configuration though so please share that with an edit

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit

Comment: This is the specific hook that's causing trouble: https://github.com/andreoliwa/nitpick/blob/develop/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml

Comment: @RoyalTS -- yeah both of those have problems, the `flake8` one will run against all files in your repository if nothing changes due to misuse of `always_run`.  and `nitpick run` unconditionally checks every file always.  they've sidestepped the framework and you should open an issue asking them to change to linting filenames which are passed

Comment: @AnthonySottile Is there any way to check default types of each hook? My test shows that the default types of `flake8` is `[python]` rather than `[file]`.

Comment: @AnthonySottile My test shows that submodules are indeed ignored by default. However, as I check with identify-cli, both a submodule and a folder return the type "directory", so how does pre-commit know which one to ignore?

Comment: @drowsyleilei you can't check "a folder" into git (only files) so only submodules are relevant

Comment: @AnthonySottile Got it. Thanks!